# "Will" vs "would" in reported speech

Tags: grammar

Suppose today is 30th November. Today my friend (John) says to me on phone "I will definitely go to the market tomorrow".

Now if I want to report his speech just after a few hours on 30th November, "will" or "would", which one should I use?

---

- Hey mom, tomorrow I will be very busy. I will have to have got ready by 10:30 tomorrow. John told me that he ***would/will*** definitely go to the market tomorrow. I can't miss the chance going there with him.

Comment: I think 100 years ago, the answer was "would". Today, you can use either one. Maybe 100 years from now, the answer will be "will". Grammar changes.

Comment: That isn’t really about reported speech. It’s purely about consistency and context… and too clearly a constructed example, too.
*John told me that he would* indicates John spoke about his intention to do something at a time that has already passed. 

*John told me that he will* indicates John spoke about his intention to do something at a time that is even now, still in the future.

*… that he would* still works if the time has passed and he hasn’t gone to the market.

*… that he will* works only when the time hasn’t yet arrived.

Answer (score -1):

Today is Monday. Yesterday my friend said "I will go to your house tomorrow". He said he would come today. The "action" of the modal verb took place yesterday = would.

Comment: In this sentence, "would" does not refer to a past action, but to a future one. It simply indicates that the assertion was made in the past.